# Ring wrap-json-body is not converting json data to keyword map, but to a string map

Tags: clojure, compojure, clojure-ring

I have come back to clojure after moderately dabbling with it about 10+ years ago, and so I might be doing something silly here.

I am trying to write a simple API with `compojure` and `ring` server, and right now I've isolated my problem to just a few lines. I have a route and a handler, and I've wrapped my handler with `wrap-json-body` as is [suggested](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json#wrap-json-body) in `ring-json` documentation.

My `handler.clj` is like so:

```
(defroutes app-routes 
  (PUT "/item/:id" {{id :id} :params body :body} (str id ", " body))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
      (middleware/wrap-json-body)
      (middleware/wrap-json-response)))
```

This should be simple enough, and I am able to return clojure data as json OK. Problem is when I'm trying to read `PUT` request body json.

```
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "id": 32, "name": "pad" }' 'localhost:3001/item/5'
5, {"id" 32, "name" "pad"}
```

I would expect `body` to be populated with `{:id 32 :name "pad"}`

Here's the whole request object:

```
; (PUT "/item/:id" body (str id body))
$ curl -XPUT -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{ "id": 32, "name": "pad" }'

{:ssl-client-cert nil, :protocol "HTTP/1.1", :remote-addr "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1", :params {:id "5"}, :route-params {:id "5"}, :headers {"user-agent" "curl/7.58.0", "host" "localhost:3001", "accept" "*/*", "content-length" "27", "content-type" "application/json"}, :server-port 3001, :content-length 27, :compojure/route [:put "/item/:id"], :content-type "application/json", :character-encoding "UTF-8", :uri "/item/5", :server-name "localhost", :query-string nil, :body {"id" 32, "name" "pad"}, :scheme :http, :request-method :put}
```

I've tweaked and changed it to a few things but I can't seem to get `:body` to be populated with keyword-ed clojure data.

What am I doing wrong please?

ps: If you'd like to see a working example of this problem, I've uploaded it to [github](https://github.com/PhosphorusGorilla/ring-json-body-test-api/blob/master/src/api/handler.clj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `keywords?` parameter in [wrap-json-body](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json/blob/0.5.1/src/ring/middleware/json.clj#L50):

```
(middleware/wrap-json-body app-routes {:keywords? true})
```

Alternatively, since ring-clojure version 0.5.1, you can specify a custom `key-fn` to convert the keys of maps:

```
(middleware/wrap-json-body app-routes {:key-fn keyword})
```

Comment: Fish in hell, that fixed it. Thanks so much! I knew I was missing something trivial.

Answer (score 1):

There also exists a "[wrap-keyword-params](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.middleware.keyword-params.html#var-wrap-keyword-params)" ring middleware which is usually placed at the end of the middleware chain and it converts all the keys in :params gathered up to that point into keywords.

Where I work at, we usually use the following pattern:

```
(def app
  (-> handler
      wrap-keyword-params ;; <--- converts any string keys in the :params map to keywords
      wrap-nested-params ;; <--- parses nested params
      wrap-params ;; <--- parses query-params into :query-params and adds parsed request body props into :params
      wrap-json-params ;; <--- parses body of a request and adds ":params" and ":json-params" keys to "request" argument (in the following format: {"key" "val"})
      wrap-json-response) ;; <--- converts response with body that is a map or a vector to JSON)
```